# Angular displays a little balloon message when a required form field is left blank. What function is being called to do that?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I would like to find the code where Angular displays a ballon when a required form field is left blank, so I can see how it's being done. Where is that happening? I haven't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. 'novalidate' turns off HTML5 form validation - we just want to use AngularJS form validation. 'ng-required=true' assigns a required value to a field i.e. without the value set the field is '$invalid'. I just used bootstrap for the label. '$dirty' is a field that has been given a value at some stage. $pristine is a field that has never had a value set. You may be able to create fancier tooltips using: 'http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##tooltips' or 'http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/'

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller="validateCtrl">
        <form name="loginForm" novalidate>
            <p>UserName:<br>
                <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.userName" ng-required="true">
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="loginForm.userName.$dirty && loginForm.userName.$invalid">
                <span class="label label-warning" ng-show="loginForm.userName.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>Password:<br>
                <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-required="true">
                <span style="color:red" ng-show="loginForm.password.$invalid">
                <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" ng-click="popupuser()" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid ">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

APP.JS

```
/*================================================================
Module - main module
=================================================================*/
angular.module('myApp', [])

/*================================================================
Controller
=================================================================*/
.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.user="";
    $scope.popupuser = function() {
        console.log("Button pressed!! ");       
        console.log("User details= "+JSON.stringify($scope.user));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is just to do this in an input tag:

```
<input class='???' type='text' ng-model='???' required />
```

Just putting `required` in the tag will give you the desired effect.

Comment: I was trying to see  how it's done, possibly to use it for other purposes.  But it seems that Angular is not displaying the balloon; the browser is doing it natively.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. It's an attribute for <input> in HTML5. As far as my research goes, ng-required='???' and required are essentially the same thing.